# Index visível ou não?

Tags: mysql

Sobre usar o parâmetro *visible* do *index* de uma tabela, gostaria de saber:

- Qual o efeito desse parâmetro em um campo de uma tabela?
- Esse parâmetro é específico do MySQL ou encontramos em outros BD?
- Irá otimizar meu index?
- Outras considerações?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa configuração faz com que o índice fique "invisível" para o otimizador de query, em outras palavras, ao executar uma query, 
esse índice vai ser ignorado pelo otimizador ao tentar montar o melhor plano para executar a query.

Mais sobre a funcionalidade aqui: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-indexes.html

**Qual a influência desse parâmetro?**

Influencia totalmente a execução das querires. Uma vez que o índice está sendo ignorado, pode mudar sensivelmete a performance, e pode gerar erros se alguma query tiver um hint
para usar o índice. No ponto de vista de manutenção do índice nada muda, ele não vai ser usado mas continua sendo atualizado.

**Esse parâmetro é específico no MySQL ou encontramos em outros BD?**

Essa pergunta é ampla demais, teria de conhecer cada banco, mas posso dizer sobre:

`SQL-SERVER` não tem uma configuração igual. No `SQL-SERVER` setar um índice como disabled tem o mesmo efeito sobre o analisador de query, ele vai se ignorado, mas o efeito
é mais abrangente: o índice é ignorado pelo banco, e não é atualizado. Pode-se, para propósito de testes usar um hint para ignorar o índice, forçar outro, etc, mas isso por query.

`ORACLE` não sou profundo conhecedor, mas existe a opção de setar um índice como disabled, mas não conheço bem as consequências.

**Irá otimizar meu index?**

O índice não, ele continuará a ser atualizado (`MYSQL`), vai influenciar na performance das querires

Para encerrar, vou citar o que diz a documentação sobre seu uso:

> Invisible indexes make it possible to test the effect of removing an
>   index on query performance, without making a destructive change that
>   must be undone should the index turn out to be required. Dropping and
>   re-adding an index can be expensive for a large table, whereas making
>   it invisible and visible are fast, in-place operations.

Em tradução livre:

> Os índices invisíveis tornam possível testar o efeito da remoção de um
>   índice no desempenho da consulta, sem fazer uma alteração destrutiva
>   que deve ser desfeita, caso o índice seja necessário. Apagar e
>   adicionar novamente um índice pode ser custoso para uma tabela grande,
>   enquanto torná-lo invisível/visível são operações rápidas e no local.